When does a finite group have finitely many indecomposable representations?
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $k=\mathbb F_p$. Then it is well-known that $G$ has finitely many irreducible modules.
However, in general $G$ does not have finitely many indecomposable representations. For example, the group $C_2\times C_2$ has infinitely many indecomposable representations over $k=\mathbb F_2$: there are indecomposable modules
$$V=\mathbb F_2\{e_0,\dots,e_n,f_1,\dots,f_n\}$$
where $(1,0)\in C_2\times C_2$ acts as $e_0\mapsto e_0$ and $e_i\mapsto e_i+f_i$ and $f_i\mapsto f_i$, and $(0,1)\in C_2\times C_2$ acts as $e_i\mapsto e_i+f_{i+1}$ and $e_n\mapsto e_n$ and $f_i\mapsto f_i$.

Is there a general criterion on $G$ that insures $G$ has finitely many indecomposable modules over $\mathbb F_p$ (or $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$)?


Yes. If $G$ is a finite group and $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$ then $kG$ has finitely many isomorphism classes of indecomposable representations if and only if the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. This is proved in a paper of Don Higman, "Indecomposable representations at characteristic $p$" (Duke 1954). The proof of this theorem gave rise to his theory of relatively projective modules.

For more details about representation type, please see Section 4.4 of my book, "Representations and Cohomology I".

That's an excellent book, by the way.

Thank you for the answer! So the counter-example I gave (which works in any positive characteristic) is essentially the only obstruction!

@anomaly Thanks! It's now pretty old.
